# Working sample of Control.VisibleChanged Event in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, events

I'm struggling to make the [MSDN code sample for the Control.VisibleChanged event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.visiblechanged(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2) work: I don't see the MsgBox.

```
Private Sub Button_HideLabel(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    myLabel.Visible = False
End Sub 'Button_HideLabel

Private Sub AddVisibleChangedEventHandler()
    AddHandler myLabel.VisibleChanged, AddressOf Label_VisibleChanged
End Sub 'AddVisibleChangedEventHandler


Private Sub Label_VisibleChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    MessageBox.Show("Visible change event raised!!!")
End Sub 'Label_VisibleChanged
```

Comment: Have you called AddVisibleChangedEventHandler somewhere, in Form_Load for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to "wire up" the events to the event handlers.

To start with, to get the code in `HideLabel_Click` to be called you need it to respond to a click on the button named "HideLabel".

There are two ways to do that: you can use [`AddHandler`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/addhandler-statement) or the [`Handles`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/handles-clause) clause.

To demonstrate the latter:

```
Option Strict On

Public Class Form1

    Private Sub HideLabel_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles HideLabel.Click
        myLabel.Visible = False
    End Sub

    Private Sub myLabel_VisibleChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles myLabel.VisibleChanged
        MessageBox.Show("Visible change event raised!!!")
    End Sub

End Class
```

***However***, you will notice that the message is shown even before the form appears. That is because of what goes on behind the scenes to create the form.

To avoid that happening, you can add the handler after the form has been shown:

```
Option Strict On

Public Class Form1

    Private Sub HideLabel_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles HideLabel.Click
        myLabel.Visible = False
    End Sub

    Private Sub myLabel_VisibleChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        MessageBox.Show("Visible change event raised!!!")
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Shown(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Shown
        AddHandler myLabel.VisibleChanged, AddressOf myLabel_VisibleChanged
    End Sub

End Class
```

Another way, in VB2015 and later, is to use a "[lambda expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/procedures/lambda-expressions)" instead of a separate method, although then you cannot disassociate the handler from the event with [`RemoveHandler`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/removehandler-statement):

```
Option Strict On

Public Class Form1

    Private Sub HideLabel_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles HideLabel.Click
        myLabel.Visible = False
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Shown(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Shown
        AddHandler myLabel.VisibleChanged, Sub() MessageBox.Show("Visible change event raised!!!")
    End Sub

End Class
```

[Craig](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2659161/craig) was kind enough to [and I quote verbatim] call attention to the importance of [`Option Strict`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/option-strict-statement) when you add handlers manually using AddHandler. Without it, the "relaxed delegate convention" may allow adding handlers which don't exactly match the event signature that you won't be able to remove later.

Having said that, Option Strict On isn't a complete safeguard: notice how my last example compiles and works even with the wrong method signature for the handler.

[I suspect that the MSDN code sample was first created in C# as part of a larger example, so some parts have been lost in the translation and excerption.]

Comment: Thanks a lot, wish you will write samples for mdsn, because some of them really lack of info :)

Comment: I would call attention to the importance of `Option Strict` when you add handlers manually using `AddHandler`.  Without it, the "relaxed delegate convention" may allow adding handlers which don't exactly match the event signature that you won't be able to remove later.

Comment: @Craig That isn't a complete safeguard: notice how my last example compiles and works even with the wrong method signature for the handler.

Comment: Interesting.  Maybe they figured that if you use a lambda (which can't be unsubscribed anyway) that it doesn't matter if it gets tweaked to fit?

Comment: @Craig If you feel like investigating what is going on, using `Sub(sender2 As Object)...`  *does* shows a problem of "Nested Sub does not have a handler that is compatible with delegate 'EventHandler'". `Sub(sender2 As Object, e2 As EventArgs)...` and `Sub()...` do not.

Answer (score 0):

I get this is old but came across this post when looking for more information on VisibleChanged and couldn't help but notice that the accept answer may be misleading. If you are using a designer to create your Form and place objects on it, then the accepted answer will be fine. In fact you can get rid of the addHandler because the designer handles that for you. All you would need to do is use a handles clause with your label.

```
Private Sub Button_HideLabel(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    myLabel.Visible = False
End Sub 'Button_HideLabel

Private Sub Label_VisibleChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles myLabel.VisibleChanged
    MessageBox.Show("Visible change event raised!!!")
End Sub 'Label_VisibleChanged
```

Where the issue lies with the accepted answer is if you arn't using a designer. Adding handle clauses to "wire up" simply won't work (we can make it work and if anyone is interested in that I'll be happy to post a code snippet of that, but it's not how the accepted answer lays it out). In your case all you need to do is call AddVisibleChangedEventHandler() to set up the handler. that's it. you could have done this by calling it in MyBase.Load

```
Private Sub Load_Form(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    AddVisibleChangedEventHandler()
End Sub

Private Sub Button_HideLabel(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    myLabel.Visible = False
End Sub 'Button_HideLabel

Private Sub Label_VisibleChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    MessageBox.Show("Visible change event raised!!!")
End Sub 'Label_VisibleChanged

Private Sub AddVisibleChangedEventHandler()
    AddHandler myLabel.VisibleChanged, AddressOf Label_VisibleChanged
End Sub
```

Once again I know this is dated but couldn't help but notice that (more or less assuming) that you are trying to get a msgBox to appear when you click a label. That is you click a label and then toggled the visibility of another label. The other label is the one where the event handler is on for visibility change. So that inevitably gets called when clicking the original label. IF you only want this msgBox to appear when clicking that label and not when the form loads as well, you should change the addHandler statement so that you are adding a handler on the click event.

Private Sub Load_Form(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
AddVisibleChangedEventHandler()
End Sub

```
Private Sub Label_VisibleChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    MessageBox.Show("Visible change event raised!!!")
End Sub 'Label_VisibleChanged

Private Sub AddVisibleChangedEventHandler()
    AddHandler otherLabel.Click, AddressOf Label_VisibleChanged
End Sub 'AddVisibleChangedEventHandler
```

Also Option Strict On has nothing to do with addhandler (From my understanding, could be wrong. please enlighten me if that is the case). Option Strict On is only checking to see that you arn't implicitly typecasting. So for example:

```
    Dim a As Double
    Dim b As Integer

    a = 10
    b = a
```

results in an error when Option Strict is On but is totally legal if it is off. So in the case of you leaving off the handles clause, you'll never be implicitly typecasting and therefore is not needed.

Hope this helps anyone who sees this question